# Ubuntu 20.04 Reading package lists... Error

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am beginner with ubuntu. I've got stuck with an error. I can't install application. Any ideas what may be wrong?

```
usic@hosttt:~$ sudo apt-get install /myprogram/program.deb
Reading package lists... Error!
E: read, still have 59 to read but none left
E: Error reading archive member header
E: Could not read meta data from /myprogram/program.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Where is the program located? Most likely the path is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 My path is like /customFolder/customerFolder/program.deb I don't use any default folders here. I couldn't install with apt but I've managed to do it with dpkg after manual dependency resolving.

Comment: Is the first "customFolder" really in the root of the FS?

Comment: @N0rbert partly yes. But anyway I don't understand why I couldn't install local package with apt

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, it is. It is on the same level with root and home directories

Comment: It looks weird to me.  Why would you place debs in such a place? Anyway you could `cd` to the place where the deb is and install in by `sudo apt ./program.deb`. `apt ` would fix the dependencies automatically.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've moved to directory with my `.deb` and run  `sudo apt ./program.deb`. It shows me error `Invalid operation ./program.deb` Then I changed to `sudo apt install ./program.deb` and now I'm experiencing the same issue like in my first post. But `sudo dpkg -i /myprogram.deb` works fine

Comment: I've recently saw "Reading package lists... Error! 
E: Could not read meta data". The issue was that I had apt build w/out some non-essential libraries, adding and rebuilding helped. Also w/out those libraries helped to copy file to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and running `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing local DEB packages, you should use `dpkg` instead of `apt`, since `apt` is designed for installing packages from the remote repositories. To install your package with `dpkg`, use the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/my/package.deb
```

Replace `/path/to/my/package.deb` with the actual path of your own package.

In some cases, this command may fail with missing dependency errors. If this is the case, issue the following command:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This will install the dependencies. After that, re-run the first `dpkg` command to install your package.

Alternatively, the program `gdebi` can be used instead of `dpkg`, since it has better resolution of dependencies without needing to `apt --fix-broken install`. To install `gdebi`, run this command:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Now you can install your program directly using:

```
sudo gdebi /path/to/my/package.deb
```

Comment: `apt` installs local packages even better than `dkpg`. It resolves dependencies.

Comment: @Daniel Massey Thank you. I made use `dpkg` it showed me dependency error. I've resolved this error with `sudo apt-get install programm`. Eventually I've installed my `.deb` with `dpkg`. Thanks again and other guys too.

Comment: `apt` takes case of (pre)-dependencies processing debs in proper order, `dpkg` does not. So sometimes for set of several debs which are one package to be installed with one go `apt` needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the `myprogram` directory is in you Home, then the path is wrong.

Run

```
sudo apt install ~/myprogram/program.deb
```