# Error: when installing the DEB packages for docker desktop on ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, docker

I am following the docs to install docker on Vmware ubuntu
when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-4.11.0-amd64.deb
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Error!

E: read, still have 8 to read but none left
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar{.zst,.lz4,.gz,.xz,.bz2,.lzma,}
E: Could not read meta data from /home/ali/docker-desktop-4.11.0-amd64.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247924/ubuntu-20-04-reading-package-lists-error

Comment: ensure the file you are installing is not damaged or incomplete downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

i was finally able to solve this

> following the installation steps here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/
>
> i was clicking on the Download the latest DEB package which downloaded the docker-desktop 4.11.0
>
> but i was able to find 4.12 from here https://desktop.docker.com/linux/main/amd64/docker-desktop-4.12.0-amd64.deb
>
> and that one worked
>
> Note: i am using ubuntu-22.04.1

Answer (score 0):

#### Had To Get The DEB File From A Different Place

Similar to Ali, and thanks Ali, the file I was downloading from the BIG BLUE BUTTON [HERE](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/debian/) would not install. I had to click on Debian for version 4.24.0 [HERE INSTEAD](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4240). Then it installed fine. This may change down the road of course for later versions, but given mine and Ali's experience, just look for different download locations if you hit similar issues. Dang!